# How to search and highlight a substring within button text? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'd like to try and search an array of buttons for a particular string... if the string is found, would it be possible to highlight (bold/underline/change text colour) the substring within it? I've already got the below code but it changes the font colour of the whole text within the button.....

`buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = Color.red;`

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

I have an array of 3 buttons with texts `bench`, `bend` and `beneficial` respectively. I'd like to search those strings for the substring `ben`. If it's found I'd like to change the text colour of just that substring within the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable [RichText](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) on the Text component itself.

You can then wrap part of text with a color markdown like so:
`<color=red>ben</color>eficial`

Code-wise, you only have to fetch the current text (and remove any markdown) first, then replace all of your occurrences of the word to match with the exact same word, but a wrapper around it, like so:

```
[SerializeField]
private Text targetText;

void Start()
{
    // Ensures that this text can support rich text.
    // (Or enable it yourself in the inspector.)
    targetText.supportRichText = true;
    WrapMatchingWordInRed("benef");
}

public void WrapMatchingWordInRed(string wordToMatch) {
    // Will remove any color-related markdown expression from your text.
    var currText = Regex.Replace(targetText.text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

    // Apply red-color to words that matches.
    string textWithMarkdown = currText.Replace(wordToMatch, "<color=red>" + wordToMatch + "</color>");

    targetText.text = textWithMarkdown;
}
```

It will look like this:

[image: image of how the result looks like]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Would I be able to do this with accessing the buttons through an array as so:
`buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text`

Comment: @Lloyd Yes, just modify the function that I have made a little bit so that it applies to all the text in your buttons. It will work as long as it is a Text, and you have enabled RichText on it.

Comment: That is just amazing! Will implement it in the morning! Thank you!

Comment: I've just marked your answer as the solution! Thank you so much! I'd really like to underline the text though... it seems silly you can't just use the <u> tag! :(